# Insert ignored route first in the route table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

It seems like ignored routes must be registered at the beginning of the collection `RouteTable.Routes`, if not it does not work. How I ensure my ignored routes are at the top of collection even though they are registered after other routes?

Comment: Register them at top. So easy, isn't it?

Comment: @Sergio I don't now how to do that, I'm using `RouteTabel.Routes.IgnoreRoute()` and I don't know what type of route I would add if I wouldn't use the extension method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick

```
RouteTable.Routes.Insert(
 0, 
 new Route(VirtualPathUtility.MakeRelative("~/", virtualPathRoot) + "{*pathInfo}", 
 new StopRoutingHandler()));
```